# how to get a alert message box containing meta data

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to know how I can obtain metadata about the page through an alert box and later save it to my DB. I have posted my code so far. I am not sure if what I have written is correct. Any help is appreciated.

**`home.html`**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
       {% if messg %}
      <script>
        alert('{{ messg }}');
      </script>
   {% endif %}
    <head>
```

**`views.py`**

```
     def info_save(request):
         try:
             request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
             message = "Info successfully saved"
             return render(request, "home.html", {"messg": message})

         except:
             message = "Info not saved"
             return render(request, "home.html")
           return render(request, "home.html", {"messg": message})
```

Comment: shouldn't the script be **in** the `<head>`, and not between `<html>` and `<head>`?

Comment: There are various ways to doing this first write script in the bottom, if not work add   {{ messg }} in **`<input value="{{ messg }}"> `** then alert val() of input

Comment: hI , can you tell me how I can call the info_save function on page load usinig javascript?